# Class Design - Avoiding redundant code

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class A extending class B .
My class B has 5 abstract methods. In all these 5 methods , I need to make one call each to a methodA() . The problem with this is that since I need to create around lets say 40 classes which extend classB , I need to write same calls for methodA , 5 times per class and in all those 40 classes.
SO I end up writing calls to methodA , around 200 times.

Now how can I design this such that I don't need to make these calls at child class level?

Example below

The methodA here is a method which logs User's action in the database.
So each time I create a class extending class B, in all the 5 abstract methods I need to call a methodA which logs user's action in database.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a concrete example of the problem?

Comment: Class a extends class b

Comment: @TedHopp, I have edited the question to make it easier to understand . Let me know if you need any othe info

Comment: what changes about the class calls?  If Class B is a subclass of class A, then you can call B.<class A method> because if it is not overridden, it exists in class B.  The same extends down the class list.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus, Sorry I didnt get your point. Class A is subclass of Class B and also the methods are overridden in Class A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pattern like this:

```
abstract public class B {
    /** Override to implement the subclass logic */
    abstract protected SomeClass reallyCalculateStuff();

    /** The public API method to be called by clients of the class */
    final public SomeClass calculateStuff() {
        executeSharedCode();
        return reallyCalculateStuff();
    }

    /** The method all other methods need to call */
    private void executeSharedCode() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class A extends B {
    @Override
    protected SomeClass reallyCalculateStuff() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You obviously would want to come up with better names. But the idea is that the base class already contains the public API and takes care of calling the shared method.

This will also work if `executeSharedCode` needs to be implemented differently in every subclass. Just make it `abstract` as well.

However, depending on the usecase, there might be better alternatives to this. For example, interceptors. It might also be worth to rethink the design as this pattern could be perhaps avoided by designing classes differently. But all those things are impossible to judge without context, so I'll just give you this pattern.

Comment: Thanks Ingo. Ya I did something similar like this earlier, Its like Template design pattern. A small issue here is that I have 10 methods in my class B with 5 as abstract method and 5 as non abstract method.

Comment: @Manish I don't see a problem with that. Can you elaborate? It might be worth adding an actual (cut down) example to your original post.

Comment: @Manish If you mean to say that you don't want to force a subclass to implement all the methods, but provide a "default implementation", just use the same idea, but instead of making the `reallyXyz` method abstract, you implement it. A subclass can then override it, but doesn't have to.

Comment: I have added the example in the question

Comment: @Manish That paragraph? No, please add actual code as an example that demonstrates what still doesn't work. In particular, please post an example of what doesn't work with my solution. What I presented does not prevent you from having non-abstract methods in any way.

Comment: @Manish This proposed solution is well established and easily understood, also by making the actual public API methods final and keeping the implementing template methods protected (a logical naming scheme by the way is to give the template methods the same name as the API methods adding simply "Impl" as suffix). Citing the mere number of methods as counterpoint is meaningless since you can clarify all ambiguity for the programmer using final for the methods not intended to be altered.

Comment: @Durandal Although "Impl" makes me shiver. I find it quite a terrible suffix, but you're right that it is well-established. But I would say that almost always there are better names. It just requires a bit more effort and, most importantly, depends on what the code actually does.

Comment: @IngoBürk, As advocated by you and Durandal, solution looks good for this problem. Thanks for hyour help!

Comment: @Manish If you still have problems, please do elaborate and we will help you further. Otherwise, if it helped you, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Other similar problem I have is that I have multiple classses A, B, C etc which dont have any commonalities but all of them have all methds which need to make call to in ClassZ.methodZ . Now how can we design this? as we cant use base class template method stuff

Comment: @Manish I would suggesting actually posting this as a new question as it seems to be different from this. Please keep in mind, however, that actual code examples replicating the problem go a long way in terms of coming up with a good answer.

Comment: @IngoBürk, I agree with u . Accepting the answer.

Comment: @IngoBürk If you already have a better set of names for a particular case, you can always use better names. The "generic" pro argument for Impl is that peoply are somewhat likely to have seen it already elsewhere, and there is a not to dismiss chance they intuitively "get" that it means there is another API method that calls it. So lets say its not the worst fallback you can take when your method naming imagination lets you down :)

Comment: @Durandal Agreed. Personally, I just don't give up even if I have to think about the name for half an hour. But then again, I would surely get my change rejected in the review if I wrote `Impl`. But in general, in the Java world, yes, `Impl` is a common thing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce code copying, you can make the methods in B non-abstract and give them method bodies. This will mean that they aren't abstract any more, but since all subclasses will inherit this behavior you can still rest assured they will all be able to use the method. Thus, the methods in B can call methodA(), even if methodA is defined in the subclasses, and they can also be overridden by your subclasses if they need unique behavior.

Comment: But I need to make all those 5 methods as abstract as I want child class to supply their own implementations.

Comment: If all the implementations are different, and the only common element is the call to methodA(), then there is no better way to do it. Just stick to calling methodA() 200 times.

Comment: alternatively, you could design your class A implementation in such a way that a passed variable would cause it to perform the different functions (if they are similar enough).  That reduces your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to intrinsically call the body of the parent class' method. You'll need to be a bit explicit about it using `super`.

Your parent class:

```
public class B {
    public methodA() {}
    public firstMethod() {
        methodA();
    }
}
```

Your implementation:

```
public class A extends B {
    public firstMethod() {
        super.firstMethod();
        // method body
    }
}
```

So, you still have to call `super.firstMethod` in your implementation, but at least this way, you can have a more extensive default implementation than a single method call.